# OutlinedTextField doesn't resize to a minimumWidth in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I'm trying to make an OutlinedTextField (see below image) act as "wrap-content". It would be ideal for it to be just big enough to fit the inside text `500g` and expand and contract if user edits the field.
If I remember correctly this was possible to do with the old views with the (non-Compose) ConstraintLayout but in Compose this isn't working.

So far I have tried adjusting various modifiers, (each separately):

```
.defaultMinSize(minWidth = 10.dp)

.width(IntrinsicSize.Min)

.widthIn(1.dp, Dp.Infinity)

.requiredWidth(IntrinsicSize.Min)
```

I also tried putting the `Row` into a Compose `ConstraintLayout`, but nothing seems to work

If I set the size modifier to a small width it does reduce the width but it no longer expands...

Anyone was able to achieve this?

[image: Outlined text field that needs to be small]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `OutlinedTextField` has default min size.

You can achieve it using a **`OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox`** together with `BasicTextField`, applying the modifier **`width(IntrinsicSize.Min)`**.

Something like:

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("500") }
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
val enabled = true
val singleLine = true

BasicTextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {text = it},
    interactionSource = interactionSource,
    enabled = enabled,
    singleLine = singleLine,
    modifier = Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Min)
) {
    TextFieldDefaults.OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox(
        value = text,
        visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
        innerTextField = it,
        singleLine = singleLine,
        enabled = enabled,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        // keep vertical paddings but change the horizontal
        contentPadding = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldWithoutLabelPadding(
            start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp
        ),
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors()
    )
}
```

[image]

**Note:** it requires at least the compose version **1.2.0**

Comment: This is fairly simple but still it is stupid for such a simple case they have still much more work on compose

Comment: This works but when I set BasicTextField.textStyle to align text to End the value is rendered as scrolled behind boundaries (partially hidden).